# Can helicopters create contrails?

Tags: helicopter, contrails

Can some or all helicopters have contrails? If only some, why only those? If not, why can they not? Pictures would be really helpful. I do know that turboprops and piston props can leave contrails, but I haven't been able to find anything about contrails on helicopters.

Comment: They don't typically fly high enough for contrails.

Comment: Typical helicopters don't, but the SA315 Lama has flown up to 40,814 ft.

Comment: Yes, as a world-record attempt, in general it does not fly anywhere near that.

Comment: You don't have to be high to leave contrails. I once saw a Cessna 150 with a short contrail while doing circuits at 1600' ASL on a cold -38C day.

Comment: Contrails behind Russian airliner at takeoff:   https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyLnu.gif

Comment: It all depends on how you define the term "contrail".  Conventionally they are considered to be the condensation of water vapor from jet exhaust at high altitudes.  However, I have seen people argue that condensation of atmospheric moisture even at sea level from wingtip vortices is considered a contrail.

Comment: @MikeSowsun I wonder if that Russian airport has a trail of deeper snow off the departure end of the runway. - haha

Comment: @MichaelHall Given that "contrail" is just short for "condensation trail"; it seems fair to me that the second definition is accurate.  That seems to be how Wikipedia treats it as well.  Nothing about the term "contrail" makes it clear that it has to be from exhaust.  If anything, that's just a bias because of how much more we observe those contrails compared to vortex induced contrails.

Comment: @JMac, except "trail" suggests something that persists after the thing that created it has passed out of sight.  But, if you will agree that when I go outside on a crisp winter day I am exhaling "contrails", then I will accept your definition!  ;)

Comment: @MichaelHall What persistence has to do with jet engines? WW2 bombers used to make contrails over much of Western Europe by their propellers. The persistence is caused by the atmospheric conditions. https://www.google.com/search?q=ww2+bomber+contrails

Comment: @Vladimir F, good point.  And I would agree those are contrails, we just aren't used to prop aircraft flying high enough to create them these days.  What I do not consider contrails are the temporary vapor trials that dissipate rapidly 10-20 feet aft of the aircraft.  But that's just my personal definition...

Comment: Once in a great while one can observe a contrail that appears to be *sheeting off the entire trailing edge* of the wing of a high-flying airliner. It usually happens near cirrostratus clouds-- rarely or never in a completely clear blue sky. Such contrails usually persist for many minutes. I strongly suspect that such a contrail would continue to form even if the engines were switched off. Whether it would be as long-lived without the moisture from the engines mixing into it, is another matter. It would be very interesting to find out.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

If the temperature and conditions are right, yes.

Any aircraft which has a heat engine that burns hydrocarbon fuel, which is pretty much any reciprocating or gas turbine engine used in aviation, will emit carbon dioxide and water vapor as byproducts of combustion.  It’s just a byproduct of the chemical reaction to produce heat energy in the engine. And when the temperatures and humidity in the ambient air are low enough and high enough respectively, the water vapor in the exhaust stream will freeze into ice crystals that remain suspended in the atmosphere for a sustained period of time.

You typically won’t see this at your average airport or from the average helicopter flying over you as the temperatures simply are not low enough at the altitude the aircraft operates at for contrails to properly form. That being said, see picture below.

[image]
Image source: https://koreaaero.tistory.com/40 (in Korean)

Comment: Carlo, that picture  appears to be vortices trailing from the rotor tips.  (and the aircraft is flying above translational lift)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I'm not sure how you can state that conclusively. Contrails don't visibly connect directly to the engines (for example: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/Contrail.fourengined.arp.jpg) and the movement of the rotors may mean they don't point directly back to the engines as a result.

Comment: @ceejayoz I use my eyes

Comment: Wooooow low altitude rotating chemtrail dispenser ! Sweet !

Comment: I very much doubt that those 'contrails' have anything to do with engine exhaust. As I asserted in my answer, the engine exhaust is hugely diluted and dispersed by the downwash and cannot possible leave a trail. The trails seen above are almost certainly from atmospheric moisture.

Comment: @Fiddlesticks Contrails from fixed wing aircraft are ‘hugely diluted by wingtip vortices as well.  A helo will produce vortices, rotor wash or no, if the conditions are right.

Comment: @CarloFelicione Fixed wing aircraft typically don't have extreme downwash directly through the exhaust stream, though. Especially not aircraft with wing-mounted engines. The wingtip vortices are normally well outboard of the engine exhaust streams.

Comment: @reirab actually there is an intermixing of engine exhaust with wingtip vortices which has limited effect on the dissipating of contrails https://cdn.aviationpros.com/files/cygnus/image/CAVC/2013/SEP/640x360/boeing-747-contrails-9740f605-_11174150.jpg

Comment: @CarloFelicione No doubt, but it's not extreme downwash directly through the exhaust stream like on most helicopters.

Comment: Not just hydrocarbon fuels, burning hydrogen fuel would also create a contrail, wouldn't it?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast The rotor will create vortices and since the turbine exhaust ports are (on most models) close to the rotor itself (because that's just where the engines are) the exhaust will be mixed with the air pushed down by the rotor. Thus the hot, humid exhaust will mix with the rotor vortices. Once the temperature gets low enough for the trails to form, they will be mostly indistinguishable from the airflow created by the rotor itself.

Comment: @gerrit yes it would.

Comment: @reirab, when the helicopter is in forward flight, it will only produce downwash comparable to a fixed wing airplane of similar size and speed.

Comment: Once in a great while one can observe a contrail that appears to be *sheeting off the entire trailing edge* of the wing of a high-flying airliner.  It usually happens near cirrostratus clouds-- rarely or never in a completely clear blue sky. Such contrails usually persist for many minutes.  I strongly suspect that such a contrail would continue to form even if the engines were switched off.  Whether it would be as long-lived without the moisture from the engines mixing into it, is another matter.  It would be very interesting to find out.

Answer (score 12):

Contrails off the engine exhausts is unlikely. But in the right conditions, ie damp air, you can get contrails off the "wingtip" vortices, ie off the rotor blade tips.

Comment: Rotor vertices are not contrails i.e. condensed water vapor from engine exhaust

Comment: @CarloFelicione I think you're over-constraining the definition of "contrails" when you shouldn't be.  "Contrail" is just short for condensation trail.  Although they are _typically_ produced by the water vapour from engine exhaust, it's not critical to their definition AFAIK.  At least [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrail) doesn't seem to think so, the article spends quite a bit of time talking about contrails due to changes in air pressure; which is what the contrails due to wingtip vortices would produce.

Comment: @JMac  "contrails" was _originally_ a contraction of those two words, but now has a clearly understood definition related to exhaust - that is why the phrase "wing tip votex" exists seperately.

Comment: @MikeBrockington The phrase "wing tip vortex" exists separately.  A wing tip vortex isn't the same thing as a contrail or a condensation trail.  A wing tip vortex can _trigger_ a condensation trail because of the low pressure zone; but a wing tip vortex and the condensation it leaves behind are two different things.

Answer (score -4):

In a word: NO.

All existing helicopters have their engine exhausts somewhere beneath the main rotor, and that means that the exhaust gases are hugely diluted and dispersed by the enormous downwash from the main rotor. It simply is not possible for a contrail to form under such dilution and turbulence.

Comment: And yet: https://www.metabunk.org/data/MetaMirrorCache/69ba2dca69ac8a46d70f85d2a2158391.jpg and https://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/newsminer.com/content/tncms/assets/v3/editorial/7/9d/79d88bd4-7008-11e2-aca8-001a4bcf6878/5111c603aa5c1.image.jpg (found at https://www.reddit.com/r/hoggit/comments/2rty2j/i_spent_30_minutes_to_get_the_huey_to_263k_only/)

Comment: @ceejayoz your comment do answer the question and thus should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @ManuH These images aren't mine, and are thus not mine to share under the StackExchange license, so my understanding is that I can't make an answer that includes them inline.

Comment: @ceejayoz why do you believe that is a contrail like the ones from a high flying jet?  See RAC's answer.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Note in the first photo what appears to be denser condensation at the bottom of the trail, in line of the engines. The first photo also debunks the idea that the rotor downwash wipes out any visible condensation put forward in this answer.

Comment: I think that this answer would be better if the first line is: "generally, no"  But that's my opinion.

Comment: @ceejayoz 1) Comments are licensed under the same terms as any other content that you share. 2) Linking to the original source is all that's required of you to be compliant to the license. You can't claim them as your _original content_.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Links to copyrighted material don't violate copyright law. Copying it over to Imgur does. Links have a tendency to die; on StackOverflow a links-only answer gets removed. I'm not familiar enough with the rules here to know if the same is true here.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Not quite, [Imgur will make no claim of copyright to any images stored by SE on the Image Server](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151461).

Comment: @ymb1 Read that answer again. "That means that the images you upload are covered under our 'attribution required' license just like anything else you contribute." I cannot license someone *else's* photos under that Creative Commons license.

Comment: @ymb1 Just because imgur won't make a claim of copyright on it doesn't mean that you can legally upload it there if someone else owns the copyright and hasn't given you permission to post it there.